# Red5 (hosted on EC2), save data to file server (hosted on different EC2)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, red5

I'm looking to utilize red5 for the project I'm on at the moment.

Scope of the project is to let the user record their video and use it as their profile video.

The issue is I couldn't find any information about saving the (video) data to different server (file server).

As the service might grow in the long run, I would like to separate the application server, red5 (media server) and file server.

Could anyone please suggest me, how to go with saving the data on a file server instead of default configuration which saves on set directory within red5.

Or if not possible, then could you please suggest me some work around (ex, sync the folder each time something is uploaded to media server)

Additional Information:
*I'm using AWS EC2 instances (Ubuntu) for all webserver, file server and media server
*web server is to display website to users using php

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should consider storing the video in S3 rather than on your own file server. Data stored in S3 will be more durable than on any file server that you can build, plus why build and maintain a file server if you don't have to? You could dispense time-limited S3 URLs to your clients and maybe even use CloudFront for CDN if appropriate.